# Keystream reuse in AES-256 in AE-2 encrypted ZIPs

Tags: aes, key-reuse, compression

Is keystream reuse a meaningful concern in AES-256 encrypted ZIP files that adhere to the [AE-2 spec](https://www.winzip.com/en/support/aes-encryption/)? From [“Attacking and Repairing the WinZip Encryption Scheme” by Tadayoshi Kohno](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Eyoshi/papers/WinZip/winzip.pdf)

> when using 256-bit AES keys, we expect collisions after encrypting 2^64 files

This seems *extremely* high to me. So high that I'm wondering if it can't be hit in a practical sense. And can't be hit for two reasons:

- The time/memory needed to construct a ZIP with so many member files
- And even with unlimited time/memory, not even Zip64 files allow getting close to this. Zip64 uses 2^64-1 as the upper bound for lots of things, but this includes offsets for blocks of bytes and they all take much more than one byte.

So if you're definitely using AES-256, this isn't a concern?

Context: I'm trying to construct a meaningful list of practical concerns if using AES-256 + AE-2 encrypted ZIP files. I'm considering *not* including the keystream reuse issue stemming from including a large number of files, because the chance of encountering it is so low it can be ignored.

Comment: did you read the next paragraph?

Comment: @kelalaka I think yes. The next paragraph seems to focus on the reasons for collisions, with focus on AES-128. It’s not obvious to me that it answers my question on if this is a concern for AES-256

Comment: The key generated for 128-bit salt  with a randomized ( not mentioned there) assumes a hash or hash based key derivations, then the usual collision applies..

Comment: @kelalaka So yes, in AE-2 with AES-256 that uses a 128 bit random salt for each file, after around 2^64 files you would expect a collision as the paper suggests. I'm trying to work out if this is so high that the chance of this can be safely ignored because when making a ZIP file, even with Zip64, you just can't get anywhere near this. I'm leaning to yes for the reasons in the question, but I think I want someone else to say it! Or: if the answer is no: why should it not be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to venture an answer. For *most* purposes this isn't a meaningful concern and the chance can be ignored.

But I think it's not quite a "1 proton in the known universe" level of "can be ignored". For cases with high numbers of files where very little risk is acceptable... I think it's worth more consideration. And specifically consideration around smaller probabilities of collisions - i.e. more risk averse than a probability of 0.5 which I think the linked paper is assuming(?)

Being inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62664761/probability-of-hash-collision and converting some of it to a Python function that works out how many files you need in a ZIP to get a certain probability of a collision:

```
from math import sqrt, log

def num_files_to_get_p_chance_collision(bits, p):
    return 2**((bits+1)/2) * sqrt(-log(1 - p))
```

I can then run

```
# The number of bits in AES-256 salt
salt_bits = 128

# Some very small probability
probability = 1/1_000_000_00
print(num_files_to_get_p_chance_collision(salt_bits, probability))
```

Which outputs `2608763578142670.0`. So to get a 1 in a billion chance of a collision, I would need to make a ZIP with ~2.6 quadrillion member files. This would be in the peta/exabyte size range at least I suspect. I'm hesitant to say no-one would *ever* put so many files in a ZIP, lest it becomes another:

> 640K ought to be enough for anyone

:-)

Bringing it back to the aim of the question:

> So if you're definitely using AES-256, this isn't a concern?
>
> Context: I'm trying to construct a meaningful list of practical concerns if using AES-256 + AE-2 encrypted ZIP files. I'm considering not including the keystream reuse issue stemming from including a large number of files, because the chance of encountering it is so low it can be ignored.

I am tempted to include a concern for *extremely* high numbers of files in *extremely* risk averse situations. Although I'm not quite sure how to quantify "extremely"...

Comment: The problem is of course that if you go for AES-256 instead of AES-128 then you're already considering such a situation... But since the salt size of AES-128 is set to 8 bytes / 64 bits I'd suggest that you have to go for AES-256 to get any kind of decent protection.